# using tomcat for jsp on apache webserver, ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, unix, tomcat

I need to be able to host jsp pages on my Apache webserver. I want Tomcat to handle any page ending with .jsp and Apache webserver to handle the other ones. I have tomcat up and running on port 8080 and apache webserver on 80.

What I want to do is the following:

```
public_html/index.html <- handled by apache webserver
public_html/example.jsp <- handled by tomcat
```

Tomcat and apache are both working individually. Any help much appericiated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tomcat [connector project](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) And more specifically [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html)